# Django template inheritance not rendered

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm following the django docs on [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance), and I think my code is correct but it doesn't work, **the template people_index.html** is not rendered.

I have three templates, base.html, base_index.html, people_index.html, each one inherited on the previous. Like this:

**base.html**

```
{% include "base/header.html" %}
<body>
{% include "base/navbar.html" %}
{% include 'base/messages.html' %}

    <div class="container container-content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</body>
</html>
```

**base_index.html**

```
{% extends "base/base.html" %}

<h3 class="snps-slim-font">Index de {{ index_of }}</h3>
<div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Filtrar</span>

    <input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese un criterio">
</div>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
        {% block table_content %}
        {% endblock table_content %}
</table>
```

And finally **people_index.html**

```
{% extends "base/base_index.html" %}
{% block table_content %}
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="snps-slim-font">APELLIDOS</th>
            <th class="snps-slim-font">NOMBRES</th>
            <th class="snps-slim-font">DOCUMENTO</th>
            <th class="snps-slim-font">CUIL</th>            
            <th class="snps-slim-font">ACCIONES</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="searchable">
        {% for person in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ person.last_names }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.first_names }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.document_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.cuil_number }}</td>           
            <td class="snps-text-align-center">
                <a href="{% url 'people:person-detail' person.id %}" title="ver perfil"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'people:person-update' person.id %}" title="editar perfil">  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
{% endblock table_content %}
```

The view if someone asks:

```
class PersonListView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'people/people_index.html'
    permission_required = ('people.can_view_list')
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PersonListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base.html` you used

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

but in `base_index.html` you didn't add them. Try to add this block in `base_index.html`.